# How to blit on the screen only once at mouse position

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to blit an image to my screen using the mouse position. This is my code.

```
#Placing the farm
if farm:


    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        hi = True
    if hi:
        screen.blit(farm_image,mouse_pos)
```

So basically I want it to blit an image to screen only once at the mouse_position when the mouse is clicked., however it displays the image not once but moves with the mouse_pos. What would I do to make the image only be displayed once at the mouse_position. I do have a main loop before this. 
What I have tried is setting hi to False after the image is blit, but that erases the image latter. Thank you for any answers you can provide!

Comment: you could define the position of the farm as an (x,y) tulpe when the button is pressed. Then using a True/False statement to make sure it is the first clic, you set the farm farm position only once. This will ensure that the farm will keep blitting at each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on PythonMaster's answer something like that might work and ensure the farm remains blitted at every frame in case you refresh all your screen with a background every time:

```
#Placing the farm
if farm:

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == False: #resets the first_click to False everytime the button is released
        first_click = False

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        if first_click == False: 
            first_click = True
        else:
            pass
        if first_click == True: #set's the farm position it will keep updating the position of the farm as you drag the mouse, if you do not want that set first_click to False here.
            farm_pos = mouse_pos
    try: #using try here, prevents errors when farm_pos is not yet defined
        screen.blit(farm_image,farm_pos)
    except:
        print 'farm position not defined yet, click to place'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using another variable to check to see if it was your first click or not:

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
    if first_click == False:
        hi = true
        first_click = True
    else:
        pass
```

Make sure to define `first_click` before you use it. This code uses `first_click` to see if you clicked once already. Its starting value is `False` and changes to `True` once the mouse has clicked. This also changes `hi` into `True` while disallowing a second click as `first_click` is no longer `False`. This leads to the `else` and `pass` statements, which do practically nothing.

Comment: It didnt work, the image still just fallows the mouse position, and when you click nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use event checking instead of state checking when you only want a single click. This is especially useful because it means you won't miss a click (which might happen if the user clicks and releases the mouse at a moment when your code isn't checking for user input). Pygame has the events `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEBUTTONUP` which both give you the position of the mouse and the button that was clicked.

How your incorporate this into your code depends on the rest of your code, e.g. if you use the pygame event queue somewhere else already. Small example:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if farm:
            screen.blit(farm_image,(event.pos[0], event.pos[1]))
```

You may use a variable to keep track of the state once the farm has been placed as suggested by PythonMaster and Sorade, or better yet, store the position and visible state of the farm in a farm object (Sprite) and simply blit it to its position whenever its state is set to visible.